# Tornado Get Reference to Instance Variable in RequestHandler

Tags: python, tornado

In writing a tornado Http Server, I am having trouble with accessing an instance variable in my main class, which contains the tornado application object as well as start method, from a separate RequestHandler object. Consider the following crude example,

```
class MyServer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ref_object = 0 
        self.application = #Add tornado.web.applicaiton here

    def change_ref_object(self, ref_obj):
        self.ref_object = ref_obj

    def start(self):
        #start the server
        pass

class SomeHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        #Yada, yada, yada

        #Call method on Myserver's ref_object
        pass
```

I need to access the ref_object instance of `MyServer` in the `post()` method of `SomeHandler` and I need to make sure that the ref_object accessed in `SomeHandler` is the same object if its changed in `change_ref_object()`.

Somehandler is only referenced as a class when creating a python tornado web server (application), and it isn't clear how one would access such an instance of `SomeHandler` to change its temporary ref_object when its changed in `MyServer`.

It basically comes down to me not understanding where the instances of SomeHandler would exist within the scope of MyServer (or specifically, MyServer's application object).

Comment: Thank you for asking this question: i have been struggling with this due to the unique structure of `tornado`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you create your `Application` object, you can pass your `ref_object` instance to `SomeHandler` by placing it in a dict as a third argument to the tuple normally used to define the handler. So, in `MyServer.__init__`:

```
self.application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/test", SomeHandler, {"ref_object" : self.ref_object}),
])
```

Then add an `initialize` method to `SomeHandler`:

```
class SomeHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, ref_object):
        self.ref_object = ref_object

    def post(self):
       self.ref_object.method()
```